# How to split the string using jquery other than split method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split the string that is coming from database. In the controller i am grouping that one and passing that value by ajax success. The same code working in other view page. But i am not able to do the splitting in my view page. What's the problem.

Code:

```
    var x = json[i].answer;
    var arr = x.split(",");
```

After this my code is getting executed. The x value will look like

```
    x = First,Last;
```

Then after splitting i will get first and last in an array.but the code does not executing after this.
   Then i have appended quotes to the string like

```
     x = "\""+json[i].answer+"\"";
```

then the split function getting executing and the array contains

```
     arr[0] = "First
     arr[1] = Last"
```

How can i solve my problem. 
Hope you understand my question

Regards,

Sri

Comment: Please add the values of `console.log(x,typeof(x))` and `console.log(json[i].answer,typeof(json[i].answer))` to your question. Probably `jsoin[i].answer` is an array and not a string.

Comment: *"How can i solve my problem."* What problem? You haven't said what you're looking for as a result. *"but the code does not executing after this"* What happens *instead*? What errors do you get in the console? What code is it that is "not executing"?

Comment: but it is working in another page

Comment: @ t.j. crowder i have given the alert to display the splitted values but the alerts are not coming

Comment: @naidu526: That comment doesn't begin to address the questions I've asked. Update the question with a **lot** more context, and the relevant code, and say what you're trying to achieve, and what errors you're getting, etc., and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: @ t.j. crowder thank you for the reply. What i am doing is i am getting the ans as said. I want to split the code and i want to assign the checkboxes to the each splitted word. But when i split it is not working

Comment: @zeta its returning an alert object

Comment: @Zeta alert(typeof(json[i].answer)); is object and           alert(x,typeof(x)) is string

Comment: @naidu526: An `alert` object? Oh, come on. Add the lines I gave to you to your code, open your web developers console (every browser has one), and have a look at the console output. Add the altered code and the output to your question. Don't EVER use `alert` to debug your code. `alert` is for, well, alerts, while `console.log` gives much more information.

Comment: @zeta i am giving this code in index page not in controller still console works for the view page. How can i find that

Comment: @naidu526: `console.log` is a ***browser*** facility (I believe it also works in node.js, but that's not the point here). You have to find the developer console yourself, usually it's contained in extras (Firefox) or something similar.

Comment: @zeta yah i found that it is also showing that it is an object

Comment: @zeta it's an array zeta